# injecting objects that rely on each other - roboguice

Tags: android, robolectric, roboguice

I successfully injected an object into my activity that takes the current activity's context in the constructor. I'm then trying to inject an object that relies on the objected i just injected. How do i make sure that i'm injecting the injected instance into the the second injected object?

My activity

```
class MainActivity extends RoboActivity{

    @Inject DataSource dataSource;
    @Inject Customer customer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);

    }
}
```

The first injected object

```
class DataSource{

    private Context context;

    @Inject
    public DataSource(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

This object relies on the previously injected object

```
class Customer{

    private DataSource datasource;

    @Inject
    public Customer(DataSource datasource){
        this.datasource = datasource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should annotate DataSource class as a `@ContextSingleton`. RoboGuice will then inject the same instance in the scope of that context.